# Assignment operations in sort() functions

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, assignment-operator

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class Int
{
public:
    Int(int i = 0) : m_i(i) { }

public:
    bool operator<(const Int& a) const { return this->m_i < a.m_i; }

    Int& operator=(const Int &a)
    {
        this->m_i = a.m_i;
        ++m_assignments;
        return *this;
    }

    static int get_assignments() { return m_assignments; }

private:
    int m_i;
    static int m_assignments;
};

int Int::m_assignments = 0;

int main()
{
    std::list<Int> l({ Int(3), Int(1) });
    l.sort();
    std::cout << (Int::get_assignments() > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    std::vector<Int> v({ Int(2), Int() });
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << (Int::get_assignments() > 0 ? 2 : 0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code prints out `02` which means that `std::list::sort()` doesn't perform any assignment operations (`operator=()`) on list's elements while `std::sort()` does perform at least 1 assignment operation on the elements of an `std::vector`.

What does the difference stem from? Container classes? Sort implementations? The `Int` class implementation?

Comment: `list::sort` is not allowed to invalidate iterators/references to elements, so it cannot copy/move them. Being a doubly linked list, it performs sorting by modifying the pointers to the previous/next elements.

Answer (score 4):

A `std::list` is a doubly linked list, meaning that it can be sorted simply by modifying *pointers* within the list. No element assignments are necessary.

A simple case would be something like:

```
head   -->   2   -->   1   -->   null
```

which can be sorted as:

```
         ______________
        |              |
        |              v
head   -'    2   <--   1   +->   null
             |             |
             '-------------'
```

without copying *any* elements.

In fact, as per `C++11 23.3.5.5 list operations /29`, the requirement to keep iterators and references valid means that, for efficiency, it really *can't* move things around:

> Effects: Sorts the list according to the `operator<` or a `Compare` function object. *Does not affect the validity of iterators and references.*

---

A `std::vector`, on the other hand, keeps its items in a contiguous array so there are no pointers to manipulate. If you want it sorted, items have to be moved around.

Comment: Can't the `vector`'s elements be moved with move assignment operator or something?

Comment: They could, yes. And if the move assignment was marked noexcept, they probably would be (coming through `std::swap`). Depends on the sort implementation.